# Django 1.7 migrations: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: db_trans_language

Tags: python, django, migration, django-1.7

I'm working on a django project and have had some migration troubles in my (test)prod setting and as a consequence have I dumped all relevant data and I am now in the process of setting up the database from scratch.

Here is what happens:

1. I remove all (potentially) faulty migrations from the app
2. I run makemigrations
3. I run migrate
4. I am presented with the following error:

Error:

```
C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Picrates>python manage.py makemigrations db_trans
C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Picrates\picrates_project
Migrations for 'db_trans':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Language
    - Create model Markup
    - Create model String
    - Create model TransMarkup
    - Create model TransString
    - Add field trans_string to string
    - Alter unique_together for string (1 constraint(s))
    - Add field trans_markup to markup
    - Alter unique_together for markup (1 constraint(s))

C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Picrates>python manage.py migrate
C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Picrates\picrates_project
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: allauth, linkedin_oauth2, crispy_forms
  Apply all migrations: account, sessions, admin, db_trans, sites, auth, contenttypes, parties, ped, socialaccount
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
  Installing custom SQL...
  Installing indexes...
Running migrations:
  Applying db_trans.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 161, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 68, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 102, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 108, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 36, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\schema.py", line 213, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\schema.py", line 125, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\schema.py", line 175, in effective_default
    default = field.get_default()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 719, in get_default
    return self.default()
  File "C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Picrates\db_trans\models.py", line 9, in get_default_priority
    max = Language.objects.all().aggregate(models.Max("fallback_priority"))["fallback_priority__max"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 325, in aggregate
    return query.get_aggregation(using=self.db, force_subq=force_subq)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 402, in get_aggregation
    result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: db_trans_language
```

Here is the created migration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations
import markupfield.fields
import db_trans.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Language',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('code', models.CharField(max_length=3)),
                ('language', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('is_public', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('fallback_priority', models.PositiveIntegerField(default=db_trans.models.get_default_priority, help_text=b'Lowest value will be first fallback language.', unique=True)),
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Markup',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('markup', markupfield.fields.MarkupField()),
                ('markup_markup_type', models.CharField(default=b'markdown', max_length=30, editable=False, choices=[(b'', b'--'), (b'html', b'html'), (b'plain', b'plain'), (b'markdown', b'markdown')])),
                ('_markup_rendered', models.TextField(editable=False)),
                ('language', models.ForeignKey(to='db_trans.Language')),
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='String',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('string', models.CharField(max_length=256)),
                ('language', models.ForeignKey(to='db_trans.Language')),
            ],
            options={
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TransMarkup',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('key', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, db_index=True)),
                ('verbose_name', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Translated Markup',
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='TransString',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('key', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, db_index=True)),
                ('verbose_name', models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Translated String',
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='string',
            name='trans_string',
            field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='strings', to='db_trans.TransString'),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='string',
            unique_together=set([('trans_string', 'language')]),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='markup',
            name='trans_markup',
            field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='markups', to='db_trans.TransMarkup'),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='markup',
            unique_together=set([('trans_markup', 'language')]),
        ),
    ]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.translation import get_language
from markupfield.fields import MarkupField


def get_default_priority():
    max = Language.objects.all().aggregate(models.Max("fallback_priority"))["fallback_priority__max"]
    if max:
        return max + 10
    return 50


class Language(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )

    language = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
    )

    is_public = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
    )

    fallback_priority = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=False,
        unique=True,
        default=get_default_priority,
        help_text="Lowest value will be first fallback language."
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        unicode = self.code
        if self.language:
            unicode += u" - " + self.language
        return unicode


class TransPhrase(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        unique=True,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        db_index=True,
    )

    verbose_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    @classmethod
    def get_translation(cls, key, description=None):
        trans_phrase, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(key=key)
        if not description:
            trans_phrase.verbose_name = description
            trans_phrase.save()
        return trans_phrase


    def render(self, wrap, csrf_token):
        raise NotImplementedError

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class TransMarkup(TransPhrase):
    def get_trans(self, language_code, use_fallback=True):
        try:
            return self.markups.get(language__code=language_code)
        except Markup.DoesNotExist:
            if use_fallback:
                fallback_markups = self.markups.all().order_by("language__fallback_priority")
                if fallback_markups:
                    return fallback_markups[0]

            language = Language.objects.get(code=language_code)
            return Markup(trans_markup=self, language=language)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"[" + self.key + u"]"

    def render(self, wrap, csrf_token):
        from db_trans.forms import SetTransMarkupForm

        markup = self.get_trans(get_language(), use_fallback=(not wrap))
        if wrap:
            context = {
                "csrf_token": csrf_token,
                "form": SetTransMarkupForm(instance=markup),
                "trans_markup": markup
            }
            return render_to_string("db_trans/set_markup.html", context)
        else:
            return markup

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Translated Markup"


class Markup(models.Model):
    markup = MarkupField(
        markup_type="markdown"
    )

    trans_markup = models.ForeignKey(
        TransMarkup,
        null=False,
        related_name="markups",
    )

    language = models.ForeignKey(
        Language,
        null=False,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.markup.rendered:
            return self.markup.rendered
        return u"[" + self.trans_markup.key + u"]"

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("trans_markup", "language")


class TransString(TransPhrase):
    def get_trans(self, language_code, use_fallback=True):
        try:
            return self.strings.get(language__code=language_code)
        except String.DoesNotExist:
            if use_fallback:
                fallback_strings = self.strings.all().order_by("language__fallback_priority")
                if fallback_strings:
                    return fallback_strings[0]

            language = Language.objects.get(code=language_code)
            return String(trans_string=self, language=language)


    def render(self, wrap, csrf_token):
        from db_trans.forms import SetTransStringForm

        string = self.get_trans(get_language(), use_fallback=(not wrap))
        if wrap:
            context = {
                "csrf_token": csrf_token,
                "form": SetTransStringForm(instance=string),
                "trans_string": string
            }
            return render_to_string("db_trans/set_string.html", context)
        else:
            return string

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Translated String"


class String(models.Model):
    string = models.CharField(
        max_length=256
    )

    trans_string = models.ForeignKey(
        TransString,
        null=False,
        related_name="strings"
    )

    language = models.ForeignKey(
        Language,
        null=False,
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.string:
            return self.string
        return u"[" + self.trans_string.key + u"]"

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("trans_string", "language")
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any foreignkey called to model db_trans_language from your current app.Please post your models.py too

Comment: Added missing models.py

Comment: A similar thing happened to me after making several changes to the model ... I do not know what happened but I have "solved" by loading a previously saved version of my project and I redid the model changes together, and at the end I did migration.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had [a similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38564851/3006854).  The offensive line is probably:

```
File "C:\Users\Sverker\Dropbox\Picrates\db_trans\models.py", line 9, in get_default_priority
  max = Language.objects.all().aggregate(models.Max("fallback_priority"))["fallback_priority__max"]
```

So here, you are querying the database with `Language.objects.all()`.  This line gets executed before the migrations are actually run, while there's still inconsistency between `models.py` and the database itself.

Try commenting out that line (and other references to `max`), and then re-run the migrations.  That's what worked for me.