# django.db.utils.OperationalError no matter what I try

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, mezzanine

OK, I'm stumped.  I think I've tried everything.

I created a model in an app's `models.py` and also added some more fields to an existing model (all with default values).  Then I ran `makemigrations`.  The result:

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: myapp_MyExistingModel.first_new_field

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/path/to/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 49, in <module>
    url(r'^someurl/', include('myapp.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/path/to/myproject/myapp/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/path/to/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    existing_model = MyExistingModel.objects.all()[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 297, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: myapp_MyExistingModel.first_new_field
```

If it matters, I'm using Mezzanine CMS and MyExistingModel is an extension of its `Page` class.  It only has one instance.

So here's what I tried next:

1. `manage.py migrate --fake`
2. `manage.py flush`
3. Renaming my database so a new one would be created

All of these threw the same traceback.  I went into the last migration for the app.  It contained an `AddModel` for my new model and a `RemoveField` for a field in the old model I renamed, but no `AddField` for the new fields I created.  So I added them to the migrations file manually and retried `manage.py migrate --fake`.  Same traceback.  I tried all the other commands too.  Same traceback.

Finally, I deleted all the app's migrations, leaving just `__init__.py`.  I also renamed the database so it would be recreated.  I retried `flush`, `makemigrations`, and `migrate` (with and without `--fake`).  All of these resulted in this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_MyExistingModel

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/path/to/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 49, in <module>
    url(r'^someurl/', include('myapp.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/path/to/myproject/myapp/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/path/to/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    existing_model = MyExistingModel.objects.all()[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 297, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_MyExistingModel
```

At this point, I have no idea what to even try next, except [start over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963186/django-1-7-migrations-django-db-utils-operationalerror-no-such-table-db-trans#comment48048112_29963186).  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: why do you do migrate --fake? That would result in the tables not being created which is probably why you are seeing this

Comment: That was the magic trick that saved me the last time I had inconsistencies between the db and migrations.  I don't think `migrate` could work before `makemigrations`, except after editing the migrations file by hand.  I just tried `migrate` without `--fake` after doing so, but that didn't work either.  I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Here's where faking saved me: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mezzanine-users/wp7TAK2L_Dg/OZXKfHRPAwAJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!  Lesson learned: read the whole stacktrace, not just the last line.  In this case, the offensive line was in my `views.py`:

```
File "/path/to/myproject/myapp/views.py", line 8, in <module>
  existing_model = MyExistingModel.objects.all()[0]
```

Like I said, `MyExistingModel` has only one instance, and this line set that instance to the local variable `existing_model` for use in the `views.py` code.

I still don't understand why `makemigrations` would need to run `views.py`.  But it does, apparently!  In doing so, `MyExistingModel` was imported from `models.py`, **including** the new fields.  But those fields hadn't yet been migrated.  Thus, OperationalError.

Comment: _"Comments greatly appreciated"_ - I suggest you open a new question, as comments are not for extended discussions.

Comment: That's true.  OK, I moved the discussion to [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/4ut03i/makemigrations_sticking_its_nose_in_my_views/).